# VS Code: No such file or directory

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Have a nested directory structure and few C programs under each directory.
    Directory hierarchy is below (B is inside A). However, I'm able to run 1.c and 2.c from VS code (ctrl+F5) but not 3.c and 4.c. When I run them it shows:

```
No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files

        A
         - 1.c
         - 2.c
         B
           - 3.c
           - 4.c
```

Can you pls suggest what am I missing in my .json files to run any program using (ctrl+F5) irrespective of it's directory location.

Comment: What do you mean by *run* a `.c` file? Do you mean compile or build? Or are each of your `.c` files intended to be stand-alone programs?

Comment: Also, do you have the exact command being run? And the directory from which it is run?

Comment: I meant compile and execute. Yes all are independent .c files.

Comment: @SimonDoppler From cmd line in VS code. I can run. But want to know why (CTRL+F5) is not working.

Comment: I think it is some issue with the task.json it is picking. Always picking the same task.json even if the .c file is in a different directory and hence failing to locate the file.